# how to Create a global function readPlayersFromFile(ifstream&) which reads all players info from afile named“players.txt"into an arrayof player objs

Tags: c++, file, class

A problem of aggregation of classes,how to Create a global function `readPlayersFromFile(ifstream&)` which reads all players
info from a file named "players.txt" into an array of player objects. Note that this file will have all of the players of all the teams that will be added later. The file will have the number of players in the file at the first line of the file.

An example file is shown:

```
100
Mohamed Salah
1992
173
48
Egyptian
//////same for the rest of players until player 100//////
```

```
Player* readPlayersFromFile(ifstream& in)
{  Player*p;
   int num;
    in>>num;
   string name;
   p=new Player[num];

   int i=0;
   while(!in.eof())
   {
        in>>p[i].getName();
        in>>p[i].getYearOfBirth();
        in>>p[i].getHeight();
        in>>p[i].getInternationalGoals();
        in>>p[i].getNationality()
        i++;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the space between player's first name and last name, the "stream operator" will not work well. Instead you should read the whole line and then convert its data to relative type:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Player {
public:
  string &getName() { return name; }
  int &getYearOfBirth() { return yearOfBirth; }
  int &getHeight() { return height; }
  int &getInternationalGoals() { return internationalGoals; }
  string &getNationality() { return nationality; }

private:
  string name;
  int yearOfBirth;
  int height;
  int internationalGoals;
  string nationality;
};

Player *readPlayersFromFile(ifstream &in) {
  Player *p;
  string line;
  int num;
  getline(in, line);
  num = stoi(line);
  p = new Player[num];

  for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    getline(in, line);
    p[i].getName() = line;
    getline(in, line);
    p[i].getYearOfBirth() = stoi(line);
    getline(in, line);
    p[i].getHeight() = stoi(line);
    getline(in, line);
    p[i].getInternationalGoals() = stoi(line);
    getline(in, line);
    p[i].getNationality() = line;
  }
  return p;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Player *myPlayer;
  myPlayer = new Player[2];
  ifstream myFile("players.txt");
  myPlayer = readPlayersFromFile(myFile);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    cout << myPlayer[i].getName() << endl;
    cout << myPlayer[i].getYearOfBirth() << endl;
    cout << myPlayer[i].getHeight() << endl;
    cout << myPlayer[i].getInternationalGoals() << endl;
    cout << myPlayer[i].getNationality() << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```